# Local mosquitto broker does not send published message to remote mosquitto broker

Tags: mosquitto

I have a problem using mosquitto bridge.

I have two ubuntu 14.04 virtual machines: B1 and B2

I have simply the following config file on B1:

```
connection mylocalhost
address serverIpAdress:1883

topic # both 2
```

B1 connects to B2 correctly

I subscribe on both machines with:

```
mosquitto_sub -d -v -t "#" -h localhost
```

When a message is published on B1 I did receive the publish on B1 but it is not received on B2.

On the other way it is working. When a message is published on B2, it is received on B2 AND B1

Do you have an idea what this could be ?

for information:
when I publish a message on B1 
I have nothing on B2 broker, 
and the following on B1 broker:

```
1539876297: Received PUBLISH from mosq_pub_3027_ubuntu-V (d0, q2, r0, m1, 'remote/titi/', ... (4 bytes)) 
1539876297: Sending PUBREC to mosq_pub_3027_ubuntu-V (Mid: 1) 
1539876297: Received PUBREL from mosq_pub_3027_ubuntu-V (Mid: 1) 
1539876297: Sending PUBCOMP to mosq_pub_3027_ubuntu-V (Mid: 1) 
1539876297: Received DISCONNECT from mosq_pub_3027_ubuntu-V
```

Comment: 14.04 is VERY old. What version of mosquitto are you using. Also is there anything in the mosquitto logs?

Comment: 14.04 goes end of life in April 2019, you should not be deploying anything new on it. Also edit the question to include the logs as it won't fit in a comment